# Stripe - Using the right react frontend component for credit card storage?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am working on a stripe backend in node and a react frontend, the idea being to create a platform for buyers and sellers. I have created the seller's side where users create `connect` accounts and add a bank to that account.

Now I want to set up the buyer's side. I want to be able to have a customer store their credit/debit card information to use to pay in the future. Below are my questions, they're a bit broad but I just want some basic guidance, not looking for code answers:

1. Should I aim to have users enter information and then have stripe create a customer object with all their information as a way of storing credit card info?
2. Can I use the `react-stripe-elements`library to facilitate this process as it seems to be made to be secure? I've been looking at the [examples](https://stripe.dev/react-stripe-elements/) but they seem to revolve around paying directly by inputting information to pay right away. Unless I am misunderstanding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I aim to have users enter information and then have stripe
> create a customer object with all their information as a way of
> storing credit card info?

Yes, the main approach is to collect the card details which will produce a PaymentMethod object that you can then save to a Customer. The easiest way to do this is by using the SetupIntents API as described here:

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse

If you follow that guide a PaymentMethod will be created automatically when you [confirm the SetupIntent](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse#confirm-the-setupintent), and since you [provide a Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse#web-create-setup-intent) when creating the SetupIntent, Stripe will automatically save the PaymentMethod to the Customer.

> Can I use the react-stripe-elementslibrary to facilitate this process
> as it seems to be made to be secure? I've been looking at the examples
> but they seem to revolve around paying directly by inputting
> information to pay right away. Unless I am misunderstanding?

You should use the new React library from Stripe instead (assuming you're on React v16.8 and above):

https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-js

The library is a simple wrapper around Stripe Elements which exposes an input field for your users to enter in their credit card details. When you use that pre-built input field from Stripe, they will automatically create PCI compliant forms for you: https://stripe.com/docs/security/guide. Otherwise, you would need to prove your business's PCI compliance annually which is a lot of work.

The client-side steps in the Save and Reuse guide all have a "React" tab that you can click on to show the React version (that uses the new react-stripe-js library):

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse#web-collect-card-details